# Reply to sender goes to dead letter box

Tags: scala, akka

I have the following unit test:

```
  it should "return xml" in new TestScope {
    val testProbe: TestProbe = TestProbe()
    val someActor = system.actorOf(Props[SomeActor])

    testProbe.send(someActor, MakeXmlApiCall())
    testProbe.expectMsgPF() {
      case Success(message) => {
        assert(message == "someMessage")
      }
    }
  }
```

For the actor with this `receive` method:

```
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case MakeXmlApiCall() => {
      val status =  Future {"someMessage"}

      println("In SomeActor")

      status onComplete {
        case Success(message) => {
          sender ! message
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

"*In SomeActor*" is printed, which means that control reaches the `receive` method.

However, I am also getting this message:

```
[INFO] [12/15/2016 18:42:29.463] [testSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://testSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://testSystem/user/$a#-1159394947] to Actor[akka://testSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

So why is the message sent to the `dead-letter` rather than the `testProbe` from the unit test.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referencing `sender()` (or any actor state) from a callback or operator on a future is not safe, since `sender()` can have changed.

You should instead use *pipe* the future back to the sender: `status.pipeTo(sender())`

In addition, your `expectMsgPF()` call does not match on what you're actually sending from `SomeActor`.  You're replying with a string, not an instance of `Success`.

Comment: How can the sender change if an Akka actor holds all messages in a FIFO queue?

Comment: Because after calling `status.onComplete`, the receive function returns and the actor processes the next message.  Futures are asynchronous, they don't block the calling thread.

Comment: `status.pipeTo(sender())` worked for me.. Awesome.. friend.. documentation goes here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/futures.html#use-with-actors